# How to fill area between curves with Plots.jl?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Suppose I have a curve `y`, and two other curves `u` and `l` in the form of vectors. How to plot:

```
plot(y, lab="estimate")
plot!(y-l, lab="lower bound")
plot!(y+u, lab="upper bound")
```

That is, an asymmetric confidence interval? I know how to plot the symmetric case with the option `ribbon` as explained [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-plot-mean-deviation-in-plots-jl/1975/5).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The current answers are ***NOT*** correct. Here are two ways that ***are*** correct (as of v1.10.1 of Plots.jl):

**Method 1**: Using `fillrange`

```
plot(x, l, fillrange = u, fillalpha = 0.35, c = 1, label = "Confidence band")
```

**Method 2**: Using `ribbon`

```
plot(x, (l .+ u) ./ 2, ribbon = (l .- u) ./ 2, fillalpha = 0.35, c = 1, label = "Confidence band")
```

(Here, `l` and `u` denote the the "lower" and "upper" y values, respectively, and `x` denotes their common x values.) The key difference between these two methods is that `fillrange` shades the region between `l` and `u`, while the `ribbon` argument is a *radius*,  i.e. half the width of the ribbon (or in other words, the vertical deviation from the midpoints).

**Example using** `fillrange`:

```
x = collect(range(0, 2, length= 100))
y1 = exp.(x)
y2 = exp.(1.3 .* x)

plot(x, y1, fillrange = y2, fillalpha = 0.35, c = 1, label = "Confidence band", legend = :topleft)
```

Let's scatter `y1` and `y2` on top of the plot, just to make sure we're filling in the right region.

```
plot!(x,y1, line = :scatter, msw = 0, ms = 2.5, label = "Lower bound")
plot!(x,y2, line = :scatter, msw = 0, ms = 2.5, label = "Upper bound")
```

Result:

[image]

**Example using** `ribbon`:

```
mid = (y1 .+ y2) ./ 2   #the midpoints (usually representing mean values)
w = (y2 .- y1) ./ 2     #the vertical deviation around the means

plot(x, mid, ribbon = w , fillalpha = 0.35, c = 1, lw = 2, legend = :topleft, label = "Mean")
plot!(x,y1, line = :scatter, msw = 0, ms = 2.5, label = "Lower bound")
plot!(x,y2, line = :scatter, msw = 0, ms = 2.5, label = "Upper bound")
```

(Here, `x`, `y1`, and `y2` are the same as before.)

Result:

[image]

Notice that the labels for `ribbon` and `fillrange` are different in the legends: the former labels the midpoints/means, while the latter labels the shaded region itself.

Some additional comments:

1. The OP's answer of `plot(y, ribbon=(l,u), lab="estimate")` is not correct (at least for Plots v1.10.1.). I realize this thread is over 3 years old, so perhaps it worked in the earlier version of Plots.jl that the OP was using at the time)
2. Similar to one of the answers given,

```
plot(x, [mid mid], fillrange=[mid .- w, mid .+ w], fillalpha=0.35, c = [1 4], label = ["Band 1" "Band 2"], legend = :topleft, dpi = 80)
```

will work, but this actually creates TWO ribbons (and hence, two icons in the legend) which may or may not be what the OP was looking for. To illustrate the point:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the option `ribbon` accepts both lower and upper bounds:

```
plot(y, ribbon=(l,u), lab="estimate")
```

Notice that by passing `l` and `u` in the `ribbon` option, the filled area will correspond to the region between `y-l` and `y+u`. In other words, `l` and `u` should be the "deviations" from the mean curve `y`.

Comment: Note that you need at least Plots v0.27.1 for this to work

Comment: If your errors are symmetrical you don't need a Tuple, just`plot(vals, ribbon=errs)` works

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? (seen [here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/131)).

```
plot([y y], fillrange=[y.-l y.+u], fillalpha=0.3, c=:orange)
plot!(y)
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. I have tried it with both GR and PyPlot as backend, but the filled area also has a line besides the filled region.

Answer (score 0):

The `fillrange` solution in @leonidas 's answer might bring an additional boundary line (at least in Plots v1.35). To remove such a line, a workaround is to specify `linealpha = 0`, that is,

```
plot(x, l, fillrange = u, fillalpha = 0.35, c = 1, label = "Confidence band", linealpha = 0)
```